# Can I use a sieve to increase frying oil life?

Tags: deep-frying

I want to start deep frying at home in a pot. I read that you can reuse the oil a couple of times and that the quality and taste decreases because of the bits at the bottom, that are being burned (basically sauted, right?) while the rest is frying.

I was thinking of using a pasta sieve inside my pot, which (hopefully) catches those bits, keeping them from burning at the bottom.

Has anyone tried that and does that sound like a good idea?

Comment: I pour the oil through a fine wire mesh strainer, after it cools and settles. It helps, a lot.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Won't the oil have taken some of the burned taste by that point?

Comment: Not much with what I deep fry. I never run more than a couple batches per meal, so the crumbs just go to dark brown, not black.

Comment: The holes (openings) in a pasta strainer are much to large to accomplish what you need to do. I concur with the advice Wayfaring Stranger offered
Yes, Minix, the oil is going to take up some of the burnt taste, that's why you can't repeat this forever. It depends too upon what you've previously fried; fish is going to impart more flavor than green beans.

Answer (score 4):

Your pasta sieve will not be fine enough and it will not prevent what you think it will. The particulates in the oil that burn are burning because your oil it hot enough to burn them. Keeping them suspended above the bottom won't prevent the burning. They will still be submerged in hot oil.

When your oil starts to get older simply run it through a very fine mesh or filter (I use coffee filters) to strain the sediment.

Comment: Is the bottom of my pot not hotter than the oil, since it is in direct contact with the heat source?

Comment: @Minix Not enough to matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can although you will need to line the strainer with something to act as a filter. We do a double lining of kitchen paper and when the oil is cooled, we run it through, jar it and refrigerate. Paper coffee filters will work well too.

Comment: He means while the oil is actively cooking.

Comment: The problem is if the sieve is made of metal it will heat and burn your hand if you don't move fast enough. If it is made of plastic it will melt. 

You might find a hot oil colander on eBay. Careful of third degree burns!